# cannot connect to proftpd on debain

Tags: proftpd

```
apt-get install proftpd
adduser alex
adduser alex root
chown -R alex:root /var/www/
nano /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
```

I add:

> DefaultRoot /var/www alex

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```

Everything seems ok, but I cannot as alex to ftp !

> 530 Login incorrect.

Comment: Anything in the syslog, or authlog?

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/ftpusers` ? User `alex` should not be listed there

Comment: Did you actually add the user alex to group root? That's what 'adduser alex root' would lead me to believe you mean.

Comment: Set a password for the user, first.

Comment: What does [ProFTPD debug logging, debug level 10](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, when you attempt to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Response tells you the server's working. It's the login that's failing. You need to set a password for user alex, using

```
passwd alex
```

If you did that and login still fails, try looking at the PAM module's recent activities using

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/auth.log
```

You should see something like "Accepted password for alex" (for auth success) or "Refused user alex for service proftpd" (for auth failure). If you don't find any entries at all for user alex in auth.log, please post your proftpd config files, as password-authentication access may not be properly configured. If you do see PAM entries for alex, try checking your proftpd log for more information on the problem.

You didn't ask about security, but please be aware that FTP is inherently insecure. Proftpd also supports SFTP, which would give you much better security. I recently posted example proftpd config for supporting both password and ssh-key sign-in for SFTP [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/771699/sftp-server-better-to-use-ssh-internal-sftp-subsystem-or-proftpd-plugin/843161#843161).